# writing a lexer in racket - having trouble with include directive

Tags: racket, lex

I would like to parse a file which has an Include directive in it. (Include )

I opened the new file and started a separat lexing function.
How can I come back to the point where I started lexing at first place?
Somehow changing the port?
I tried parameterize and make-parameter but lexing stops after the eof trigger.

Any help will be appreciated.

Dietmar

Hopefully It won't get too big and ugly :

Example:

```
##defineSource asduv1          
Include default-asduv1.inc     


##defineSource asduv2            
set USESGS 1                      

# +++ MSG_TYPE +++
# METAR oder SPECI
#
DefSequence MSG_TYPE  { "METAR" }                                           
DefSequence WIND      { "23E1WKT" }
.
.                                     
.
```

A `##defineSource <protocol>` starts a new "data definition section"
which is followed by either an Include  or
lots of `DefSequence <VAR> <List of Values>` definitions.

By the way -> the hole story is in tcl

Comment: Can you give a concrete program that shows the problem?

Comment: Agreed... it's *very* unclear what your larger goal is, here.

Comment: I think the racket flag is a mistake. Should probably be `tcl` instead.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers - but is's off topic for quite a while